# GeoServer rendering lines distorted at an angle

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-styling

I am trying to render a line layer in GeoServer. The line layer has many segments. If I apply a `stroke-width: 20px`, the lines are rendered distorted at an angle.
Below is the styling code

```
* {
  stroke-width: 20px;
    stroke: red;
}
```

The line has a **EPSG:28350** projection. I checked the GeoServer log and there is no error.

[image]

When I zoom in closer the segments are rendered correctly.

[image]

Any ideas on what is causing this problem and how to fix it?

This is the content of GEOTOOLS_DEVELOPER_LOGGING.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This log4j configuration file needs to stay here, and is used as a default logging setup   -->
<!-- during data_dir upgrades and in case the chosen logging config isn't available.            -->
<Configuration name="GEOTOOLS_DEVELOPER_LOGGING" status="fatal" dest="out">
    <!-- As GeoTools uses java.util.logging levels instead of log4j, GeoServer makes the        -->
    <!-- following mappings to adjust the log4j levels specified in this file.                  -->
    <!--                                                                                        -->
    <!-- Log4J Level          java.util.logging Level                                           -->
    <!-- ==================== =======================                                           -->
    <!-- ALL                   ALL                                                              -->
    <!-- FINEST                FINEST                                                           -->
    <!-- TRACE                 FINER                                                            -->
    <!-- DEBUG                 FINE                                                             -->
    <!-- CONFIG                CONFIG                                                           -->
    <!-- INFO                  INFO                                                             -->
    <!-- WARN                  WARNING                                                          -->
    <!-- ERROR                 SEVERE                                                           -->
    <!-- FATAL                 FATAL                                                            -->
    <!-- OFF                   OFF                                                              -->
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="stdout" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%date{dd MMM HH:mm:ss} %-6level [%logger{2}] - %msg%n%throwable{filters(org.junit,org.apache.maven,sun.reflect,java.lang.reflect)}"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="geoserverlogfile">
            <filename>logs/geoserver.log</filename>
            <filePattern>logs/geoserver-%i.log</filePattern>
            <PatternLayout pattern="%date{dd MMM HH:mm:ss} %-6level [%logger{2}] - %msg%n%throwable{filters(org.junit,org.apache.maven,sun.reflect,java.lang.reflect)}"/>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="3" fileIndex="min"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>

        <Logger name="org.geotools" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="geoserverlogfile"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.geotools.factory" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="geoserverlogfile"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.geotools.renderer" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="geoserverlogfile"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.geotools.data" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="geoserverlogfile"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.geotools.feature" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="geoserverlogfile"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.geotools.filter" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="geoserverlogfile"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.geotools.filter" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="geoserverlogfile"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="org.geoserver" level="CONFIG" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="geoserverlogfile"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.vfny.geoserver" level="CONFIG" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="geoserverlogfile"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="org.springframework" level="warn" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="geoserverlogfile"/>
        </Logger>

        <Root level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="geoserverlogfile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: what projection is your data in? we also need to see the SLD, and relevant part of the log file at GeoTools debug level

Comment: I styled with css and there is no error in the geoserver log.

Comment: OK, then we need to see the CSS file and know the projection etc of the data and we need to see what is in the log even if there is no error, with out this information all we have is two pictures and no clue as to what is happening

Comment: Not sure how and where to get log. There is nothing in the Geoserver logs. The data is projected in EPSG:28350, and the css style * {
  stroke-width: 20px;
    stroke: red;
}